# Select Query works but Update Query does not work in Postgresql from dot net code using NpgsqlCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I am trying to update username from MVC .Net C# after connecting Postgres SQL.
I am able to establish the connection and if I run select command I am able to get the result.
But when I am trying to update record no error comes but updated count comes 0. Record available in database.
Can you please suggest what could be the reason.

```
using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string query = string.Format("UPDATE um_user SET um_user_name='{0}' WHERE um_user_name='{1}'", updatedUser, userNameToBeUpdated);
                    con.Open();
                    NpgsqlCommand comn = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                    comn.Connection = con;
                    updatedRows = comn.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    comn.Dispose();
                    con.Close();
                }
```

I have added using parameter as well with the following code but still getting 0 updtaed rows.

```
using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection())
                {
                    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                    connection.Open();
                    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandText = "update um_user set um_user_name=@newName where um_user_name=@oldName";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@newName", updatedUser));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@oldName", userNameToBeUpdated));
                    updatedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

Comment: (Possible) side note: Don't use `string.Format()` to get values into the query, use parameters,

Comment: Presumably your string is not being escaped properly. Always use parameters for queries, this is both from a *security* aspect and *correctness*

Comment: I tried with parameter but still updated count returns 0. I have added new code which I applied. @stickybit

Comment: Sorry it was my bad some issue in connection string. Issue got resolved with correct connection.